# has Loopback Model got "exists" method with where clause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I would like to use query the data using filter but only to check whether it exists.

Does loopback support the following way to querying? if yes, can you please share the pointer?

```
myModel.exists({where: {and: [{city: "London"}, {gender: "F"}]}}, function(err, bool){
 if(bool) callback();
});
```

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot use a filter object with the `exists()` method, instead, you can use a simple `find()` call with your filter object and then check the length of the returned array:

```
myModel.find(
    // I added a "limit" so that we don't do any unnecessary looking
    {where: {and: [{city: "London"}, {gender: "F"}]}, limit: 1},
    function(err, records){
        if(!records.length) {
            // no matching records exist!
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Well, this is how I am also using it.. except using findOne but I wanted to reduce my callback hell by avoiding more nested logic. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It also appears the exists method only accepts in the primary `id` as well. http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/#persistedmodel-exists